# Upload a file from local folder to aws s3 bucket using robot automation testing framework

Tags: amazon-s3, robotframework

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Allowed Methods' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has

no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Create Bucket' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has n

o attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Create Session With Keys' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'ins

pect' has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Create Session With Profile' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module '

inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Delete All Sessions' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect'

has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Delete File' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no

attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Delete Session' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has

no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Download File' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has n

o attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Key Should Exist' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' ha

s no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Key Should Not Exist' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect

' has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Local File Should Exist' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'insp

ect' has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Local File Should Not Exist' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module '

inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'Upload File' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no

attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'database_exists' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has

no attribute 'getargspec'

[ ERROR ] Error in library 'AWSLibrary': Adding keyword 'dynamo_query' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no

attribute 'getargspec'

[ WARN ] Imported library 'AWSLibrary' contains no keywords.

==============================================================================

Tc

==============================================================================

Upload File                                                           | FAIL |

No keyword with name 'Create Session With Keys' found.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Upload file to S3 folder                                              | FAIL |

No keyword with name 'Create Session With Keys' found.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tc                                                                    | FAIL |

2 tests, 0 passed, 2 failed

==============================================================================

Output:  C:\Users\wa616\secondrotation\AWS_Project\output.xml

Log:     C:\Users\wa616\secondrotation\AWS_Project\log.html

Report:  C:\Users\wa616\secondrotation\AWS_Project\report.html

(.venv) PS C:\Users\wa616\secondrotation\AWS_Project>

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  AWSLibrary

*** Variables ***
${REGION}=  us-east-1
${BUCKET}=  device-data-log-dev
${KEY}=  upload.csv
${PATH}=  C:\Users\wa616\Desktop\AutomationCodee\upload.csv
${s3FolderName}=  bosch-device

*** Test Cases ***
Upload File
    Create Session With Keys  ${REGION}  ${ACCESS_KEY}  ${SECRET_KEY}
    Upload File  ${BUCKET}  ${KEY}  ${PATH}
    Key Should Exist  ${BUCKET}  ${KEY}
    Delete File  ${BUCKET}  ${KEY}
    Delete All Sessions

*** Test Cases ***
Upload file to S3 folder
    ${uploadKey}    Set Variable    ${s3FolderName}/upload.csv
    ${uploadPath}    Set Variable    ${PATH}/upload.csv
    Create Session With Keys    ${REGION}  ${ACCESS_KEY}  ${SECRET_KEY}
    Upload File    ${BUCKET}    ${uploadKey}    ${uploadPath}
```

Comment: inspect.getargspec() has been removed in python 3.11 and robotframework-aws has not been updated  to fix this issue.  Your options; downgrade your python to 3.10 *or*  fix the issue and submit a patch to https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-aws

Comment: Hi ,Rasjani earlier error removed after downgrading python 3.12 to 3.10. now I'm facing another issue:Upload File to S3 Folder                                              | FAIL |
S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload C:/Users/wa616/Desktop/AutomationCodee/upload.csv to device-data-log-dev/upload.csv: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the P
utObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. I'm entering correct access key and secret access key still getting this error.pls help me to resolve this issue.---------------------------------